# Same Python code , different performance

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, kdtree

I wrote this code in Python and there's something driving me crazy. The same code when I put in function, give me different results!! How that can be? This is the code in the main and the same code in a function

```
def iterateTesting(k):
    Accuracy = []
    for t in range(0,10):
        train_data,test_data = shuffleAndSplit(data)
        acurracy = test(train_data,test_data,k)
        Accuracy.append(acurracy)
    print ('{0:.2f}% , {1:.2f}').format(np.mean(Accuracy),np.std(Accuracy))

data = getData("d.data")


train_data,test_data = shuffleAndSplit(data)
Accuracy = []
for t in range(0,10):
    train_data,test_data = shuffleAndSplit(data)
    acurracy = test(train_data,test_data,1)
    Accuracy.append(acurracy)
print ('{0:.2f}% , {1:.2f}').format(np.mean(Accuracy),np.std(Accuracy))
iterateTesting(1)
```

I get around 55% from the function and 65% from the main everytime I run the code. I'm calling the same functions and using the same data. I will really appreciate if someone clarify. Thanks

Comment: Why are there **three** `train_data,test_data = shuffleAndSplit(data)` lines if you've repeated the code **twice**?

Comment: Try repeating the entire loop in the main body (instead of once in main and once in a function) and see if you get similar results.

Comment: Are you setting the seed for `shuffleAndSplit`?

Comment: To clarify the code, I'm testing the data 10 times to take the mean and I'm shuffling it and split it before each time. I do the same exact code in a function. However, I'm getting different mean. Every time I run the code I get in the main body mean from 63 to 70 while in a function I get from 53to 58. Same code different results. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by defining training and testing data as global variables in my function